# How to sort 2D list by columns?

Tags: python, nested-lists

I would like to take a 2D list like this:

```
initial_table = [
    [1, 2, 3],
    [5, 4, 3],
    [2, 3, 4]
]
```

and sort each column vertically to get:

```
sorted_table = [
    [1, 2, 3],
    [2, 3, 3],
    [5, 4, 4]
]
```

Edit: I have tried using `sorted_table = sorted(initial_table, key=lambda a:a[0])` but that just sorts one column, is there a way to make it sort multiple?

Comment: What have you tried? This site is not meant for providing code, we expect you to ask about a specific issue.

Comment: I'm assuming the 1st one in the bottom row is supposed to be a 5?

Comment: yeah sorry, changed it.

Comment: Have you read the [Sorting HOW TO](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/sorting.html) guide in the documentation? Note especially what it says at the end of the [The Old Way Using Decorate-Sort-Undecorate](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/sorting.html#the-old-way-using-decorate-sort-undecorate) section about the `key` function—it's key to doing what you want (pun intended).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[numpy](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.sort.html) is your friend!

```
import numpy as np

initial_table = [
    [1, 2, 3],
    [5, 4, 3],
    [2, 3, 4]
]

np.sort(np.array(initial_table), axis=0)

>> array([[1, 2, 3],
          [2, 3, 3],
          [5, 4, 4]])
```

Answer (score 3):

Transpose using `zip(*l)` to get a list of columns, then sort each individual column, then transpose back:

```
list(zip(*(sorted(col) for col in zip(*initial_table))))
```

Step by step output:

```
print(list(zip(*initial_table)))
# [(1, 5, 2), (2, 4, 3), (3, 3, 4)]
print([sorted(l) for l in zip(*initial_table)])
# [[1, 2, 5], [2, 3, 4], [3, 3, 4]]
print(list(zip(*(sorted(col) for col in zip(*initial_table)))))
# [(1, 2, 3), (2, 3, 3), (5, 4, 4)]
```